# My periodic task that is the background agent is not getting called again and again in windows phone 7.1

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile

I created a simple periodic task that will show a toast message every 15 seconds. But it just shows the toast only once and never again. I am running the project in the debug mode only.
Here is my code. Where am i making a mistake?

//THIS IS THE MAINPAGE CODE

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // A unique name for your task. It is used to 
    // locate it in from the service.
    var TASK_NAME = "ScheduledTaskAgent1";

    PeriodicTask task = new PeriodicTask(TASK_NAME);
    task.Description = "This is our custom agent for Day 25 - Background Agents";
    ScheduledActionService.Add(task);
    ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(TASK_NAME,
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1500));
}
```

//THIS IS THE SCHEDULEDTASKAGENT CODE

```
protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
{
    //TODO: Add code to perform your task in background
    ShellToast popupMessage = new ShellToast()
    {
        Title = "My First Agent",
        Content = "Background Task Launched",
    };
    popupMessage.Show();
    NotifyComplete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LaunchForTest invokes your task once after the specified delay which, by the way, you have specified as 1.5 seconds not 15. In your OnInvoke, add the folowing before NotifyComplete();

```
ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest(task.Name, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
```

Don't forget, LaunchForTest is intended for development and should not be used in a release build.

Comment: Whether its 1.5 or 15 its not repeating. I tried what you said and its not working.

Comment: This link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: At last it worked. But its getting updated once every 30 mins. The debug mode is not working. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't invoke a task so often. The system launches your agent in ~28 mins. Constraints for periodic agents are listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforPeriodicAgents